# JavaScript error in HERE maps

Tags: here-api

HERE Maps JavaScript API errors in Firefox and Chrome (but not IE) when there are style sheets in the body.

Working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Working</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.w3.org/2008/site/css/minimum" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 500px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        nokia.Settings.set('appId', *REMOVED*);
        nokia.Settings.set('authenticationToken', *REMOVED*);
        new nokia.maps.map.Display(document.getElementById('map'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Failing Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Failing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 500px"></div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.w3.org/2008/site/css/minimum" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        nokia.Settings.set('appId', *REMOVED*);
        nokia.Settings.set('authenticationToken', *REMOVED*);
        new nokia.maps.map.Display(document.getElementById('map'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem appears to be from the following logic:

```
var f = c.styleSheets, p = f.length, a, k, m = c.createElement("style");
m.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
c.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(m);
a = f[f.length - 1];
```

It looks like what's happening is document.styleSheets will have elements in the body after elements in the head, so this tries to manipulate an external style sheet instead of the style element it just created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-link-element) on **link**:

> If the **rel** attribute is used, the **link** element is restricted to the **head**
>   element....

Therefore your HTML5 markup is invalid, since the **link** should not occur within the **body**, this is metadata content which should be placed in the **head**. Obviously IE is being more lenient for some reason (I guess there must be some sort of IE specific code being used here to try and get it to be standards compliant, which happens to accept the **link** in a **body** as a by-product)

Comment: Thanks for this response. I know that's invalid HTML, but unfortunately every browser supports it. What can happen is that our application is embedded into other websites, which puts us at the mercy of their HTML validity.

Comment: For anyone reading this later, we ended up putting the map into an iframe. The map code is happy there, and it's much easier than getting third parties to fix their websites.